# Unity3D - I can't make account creation system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates

I'm trying to create an account creation system within Unity, but I run into the following error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name Response could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

**Script NetworkConnection**:

```
public void CreateUser(string userName , string email , string pass , Action<Response> response){
     StartCoroutine (Make_CreateUser (userName, email, pass, response));
 }
 private IEnumerator Make_CreateUser(string userName , string email , string pass , Action<Response> response){
     WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
     form.AddField ("userName", userName);
     form.AddField ("email", email);
     form.AddField ("pass", pass);

     WWW w = new WWW ("http://localhost/game/createUser.php", form);

     yield return w;
     response (JsonUtility.FromJson<Response> (w.text));
 }
 [Serializable]
 public class Response {
     public bool done       = false;
     public string message = "";
 }
```

**MenuController script:**

```
[SerializeField] private InputField userNameInput     = null;
 [SerializeField] private InputField emailInput         = null;
 [SerializeField] private InputField passwordInput     = null;
 [SerializeField] private InputField RepasswordInput     = null;
 [SerializeField] private Text textInput             = null;
 private NetworkConnection s_NetworkConnection =  null;
 public GameObject Register;
 private void Awake(){
     s_NetworkConnection = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<NetworkConnection> ();
 }
 public void SubmitRegister(){
     if (userNameInput.text == "" || emailInput.text == "" || passwordInput.text == "" || RepasswordInput.text == "") {
         textInput.text = "Please, complete all fields";
         return;
     }
     if (passwordInput.text == RepasswordInput.text) {
         textInput.text = "Loading...";
         s_NetworkConnection.CreateUser (userNameInput.text, emailInput.text, passwordInput.text, delegate (Response response) {
             textInput.text = response.message;
         });
     } else {
         textInput.text = "Passwords are not equals";
     }
 }
 public void OnMouseDown ()
 {
     Register.SetActive (!Register.activeSelf);
 }
```

The problem is in the **MenuController** script in this snippet:

> s_NetworkConnection.CreateUser (userNameInput.text, emailInput.text, passwordInput.text, delegate (Response response) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `Response` class  is *declared* or *nested* inside the `NetworkConnection` script making it directly inaccessible from other scripts:

```
public class NetworkConnection : MonoBehaviour
{
     .....

    [Serializable]
    public class Response
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

You have two options when trying to use it:

**1**.Provide the class that the `Response`class is inside when trying to reference `Response`. In this case that's the `NetworkConnection` class.

So change

```
s_NetworkConnection.CreateUser(userNameInput.text, emailInput.text,
    passwordInput.text, delegate (Response response)
{
    textInput.text = response.message;
});
```

to

```
textInput.text = "Loading...";
s_NetworkConnection.CreateUser(userNameInput.text, emailInput.text,
    passwordInput.text, delegate (NetworkConnection.Response response)
{
    textInput.text = response.message;
});
```

Notice how `Response` now has `NetworkConnection.` in front of it.

---

**2**.Another option is just to move the `Response` class outside the `NetworkConnection` class. That should make it accessible directly from other scripts.

Change

```
public class NetworkConnection : MonoBehaviour
{
    .....

    [Serializable]
    public class Response
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

to

```
public class NetworkConnection : MonoBehaviour
{
    .....
}

[Serializable]
public class Response
{
    .....
}
```

Comment: I used the first option and in the Editor there were no more errors, but when I press the register button, the following error appears on the console: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Your compile-time error is now fixed. The run-time error is not relevant. Please create a new post for that. While on it, make sure to past the complete classes with their names, also double-click on the error then post the line of code that is causing it. There are required to help you in your new issue.